# Как графически выделить на карте Leaflet маркер по клику?

Tags: reactjs, leafletjs

Как можно графически выделить по клику маркер?
Popup и Tooltip не подходят.
Искал backline (подсветка), underline (подчёркивание) - не нашёл. Какие ещё могут быть варианты?

Можно менять стандартную синюю иконку на, например, красную, но это только если ничего другое не найду.